# Generic Search Algorithms for Qt container classes

Tags: c++, qt, stl, containers

The STL overs a variety of functions to find elements in container classes. Are there similar functions in for Qt 5.5 container classes e.g. `QList` or `QVector`?

Especially, I'm looking for an equivalent one-liner i.e. `std::find_if` using Qt containers and Qt algorithms:

```
int main(int arg, char** args) {
    std::vector<int> c = { 2,3,4,6,6,15 };
    if (std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [](const int& value) { return value % 5 == 0; }) != c.end()) {
        std::cout << "At least one element divisible by 5." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No element is divisible by 5." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The predicate of an element being divisible by 5 should be just serve as an example.

Does the Qt Framework provides such nice algorithms?

Comment: Why do you want Qt to duplicate the STL algorithms? Just use `std::find_if` on Qt containers such as `QVector`, it works fine. There is `QVector::indexOf` and some others, I didn't find a `find_if` version.

Comment: Yes. Me too. I was asking myself, if I just wasn't able to correctly search in the docs. Maybe I really have to convert back and forth between `QVector` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @FrankSimon Why do you want convert from / to `std::vector`? You can call `std::find_if` directly with a `QVector`.

Comment: Ah. Now I got it. The `QVector` interface is compatible with the `STL` ? That is really ingenious.

Comment: It may worth a note that Qt earlier provided equivalents of STL algorithms, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#details, but starting from Qt 5.0 using of STL implementations directly is encouraged

Answer (score 7, accepted):

STL algorithms defined in `algorithm` header can be used with Qt containers. If Qt lacks an equivalent algorithm there is no reason to avoid using the STL algorithm. If Qt is built with STL support it should work by default.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::find_if
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QVector<int> c{ 2,3,4,6,6,15 };
    if (std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [](const int& value) { return value % 5 == 0; }) != c.end()) {
        ...
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The other people here already pointed that out. See the comments. Thanks for the reply. I already found a working solution, it's really easy.

Answer (score 1):

The standard C++ algorithms are meant to work with any container that fulfills the requirements of a given algorithm. The relevant standard containers are not special here: they happen to fulfill the requirements. Just as Qt containers do, and plenty of other containers. You'd be expected to write your own containers or iterator adapters in the course of your work anyway, specifically to leverage the standard algorithms.

For example, you can have an iterator adapter for [QGraphicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32569402/1329652) or [QLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546609/1329652), or have to create [an iterator for circular data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9993713/1329652).