# Qt/C++ : Is "static_cast" ok for casting in this snippet of code?

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I am using Qt5 on Windows 7. In my current app I have the following piece of code that changes the background color of some push-buttons:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < layout()->count(); i++)
{
    QPushButton * button = static_cast<QPushButton*>(layout()->itemAt(i)->widget());
    button->setStyleSheet(backgroundColor);
}
```

Well, I have 2 questions about the above code:

1. Is it ok/correct to use `static_cast` or should I use some other type of casting?
2. Is it possible to use `foreach` instead of the `for loop` above?

Comment: What is the type of `layout()->itemAt(i)->widget()`?

Comment: You probably want `qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(layout()->itemAt(i)->widget())` and check the return value is not nullptr.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is `QWidget`, so it is better to use dynamic/qobject cast.

Comment: `layout()->itemAt(i)->widget()` returns _QWidget *_ .

Comment: Then I would follow @VictorPolevoy advice.

Comment: If you sure, that there will be only `QPushButton`s in layout, then `static_cast` is OK

Comment: @VictorPolevoy note: `qobject_cast` is much faster than `dynamic_cast` and it doesn't require RTTI.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov i know that / that is why I included it in my comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) so you can check if the cast was successful. It returns 0 if the cast failed.

```
QPushButton * button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(layout()->itemAt(i)->widget());
if(button)
    // cast ok
else
    // cast failed
```

You can't use [`foreach`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword) as you would need a container for that.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically acceptable to use `static_cast` only if you're sure that the layout only contains widget items **and** they all contain a `QPushButton`. Since this is error prone in face of code modifications, I don't suggest doing it.

Instead, it is desirable to use range-for in C++11 or `foreach`/`Q_FOREACH` by using a [layout iterator adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546609/1329652). The iterator adapter also solves the problem of iterating only the elements of a type you desire and makes your code safe in face of modifications.

Your can then use range-for and this code is safe even if no `QPushButton`s are in the layout, and will cope with any kind of layout item gracefully by ignoring it as it should:

```
for (auto button : IterableLayoutAdapter<QPushButton>(layout())) 
  button->setStyleSheet(backgroundColor);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I followed the link you provided above. You said something like using `foreach` in C++11 is a bad thing. Why is that?

Comment: @groenhen Because it's a butt-ugly macro that can sometimes bite you, and you've got range-for for a reason: so that you'd use it!

Comment: Geee, it seems `foreach` is something Qt-specific. So, I guess your aversion on it is because it is kinda polluting C++ code... OTOH, I was just wondering if `range-for` has any advantage over simple `for` loop, I mean something like smaller code and/or faster code?...

Comment: @groenhen Range-for clearly expresses your intent and is subject to a number of optimizations that might fail otherwise. In a `for` loop, you have an induction variable or an iterator - good if you need them, but if your intent is "give me all elements (perhaps fulfilling a criterion) from a collection", then the induction variable/iterator is a distracting implementation detail and range-for is **the** direct way of writing it. `foreach` was a necessary hack in pre-C++11 days. 5 years into C++11's reign there's no point to it, except if your code needs to be compiled using obsolete tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all widgets are QPushButtons, then yes, static_cast is the best option (most efficient)
Regarding the foreach, I'm not sure you can get the QLayoutItems as some standard container, so I'm not sure you can do it.