# Qt GUI how can I put these labels into an array

Tags: c++, qt

How can I set up my `labels` to be in an array to be called on later? I can't seem to get a hand on what type `labels` is in order to pull this off.

What I have is this, however this would be rather ugly to maintain.
If I could change this

```
ui->label_11->setVisible(false);
ui->label_5->setVisible(false);
ui->label_12->setVisible(false);
ui->label_44->setVisible(false);
ui->label_43->setVisible(false);
ui->label_9->setVisible(false);
ui->label_10->setVisible(false);
ui->label_42->setVisible(false);
```

to this, it would be most preferable. But, perhaps I'm thinking about this in the wrong way.

```
SometypeIdoNotKnow values[7] = {ui->label_11,    
                                ui->label_5,
                                ui->label_12,
                                ui->label_44,
                                ui->label_43,
                                ui->label_9,
                                ui->label_10,
                                ui->label_42};

for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){    
    values[i]->setVisible(false);    
}
```

Comment: BTW, Your example has UB. I mean `SometypeIdoNotKnow values[7]` then `for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){ `

Comment: How about instead `QList<QLabel*> labels = findChildren<QLabel*>();` Which will give you a list of all the labels that exist in the parent widget.

Comment: SometypeIdoNotKnow is a `QLabel*`

Comment: @drescherjm Good idea, but it assumes that the all the labels are to be iterated.

Comment: I was thinking of that part. If you only need to iterate a subset of that you may still be able to use `findChildren<QLabel*>()` perhaps making use `QRegularExpression` parameter (name the labels the same base object name) and / or filter however it depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler is not ancient, use C++11:

```
// If you only want to iterate some labels
auto const labels = {ui->label_11, ui->label_12, ui->label_44, 
                     ui->label_43, ui->label_9, ui->label_10, 
                     ui->label_42};
// If you want to iterate all labels
auto labels = findChildren<QLabel*>();

for (auto label : labels) label->hide();
```

Comment: what is up with the auto type? That is really cool how that is working :) Thank you for showing me

Comment: also how can i get all the children under a certain parent? Say under `verticalLayout`

Comment: @tisaconundrum A layout isn't a parent in the sense of a `QObject` parent. Iteration of widgets managed by a given layout is covered by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31546511/1329652).

Comment: @tisaconundrum "what is up with the auto type" It's not a type. It's an instruction for the compiler to perform type inference. It is a 5+ year old feature of modern C++. You might wish to read up on C++11, it allows your code to be much more readable and concise compared to C++98.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @drescherjm for the answer.

this seems to have worked.

```
QLabel* values[7] = {ui->label_11, 
                     ui->label_12, 
                     ui->label_44, 
                     ui->label_43, 
                     ui->label_9,  
                     ui->label_10, 
                     ui->label_42};
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){       
    values[i]->setVisible(false);  
    qDebug() << i;                 
}
```